# Cartan or Coxeter matrix of an algebra of infinite global dimension

Tags: representation-theory, quiver

Let $(Q, I)$ be a bound quiver such that $A=KQ/I$ has  infinite global dimension.

I want to ask the following questionss:

(1) Is the Cartan matrix $C_A$ of $A$ invertible in the matrix ring $M_n(Z)$?

(2) what are the relations between the Cartan matrix ( or Coxeter  matrix) of  a finite dimensional algebra $B$ and the global dimension of $B$? ( Here $B$ may have infinite global dimension)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) No.  Example:
$$ \begin{array}{ccc} & \alpha & \\ 1 & \rightleftarrows & 2 \\ & \beta & \end{array}$$
with all paths of length 3 = 0.  This is a symmetric algebra wigh Loewy structure
$$ \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & & 2\\ 2 & \oplus & 1 \\ 1 & & 2 \end{array}$$
and has infinite global dimension.  Its Cartan matrix is 
$$ \left(\begin{array}{cc} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{array}\right) $$
whose determinant is not 1, hence not inveritble in $\mathrm{Mat}_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

(2)  In general, I don't know.  But this is (partly) known for cellular algebras.  (And I think BGG algebras, which always is of finite gloabl dimension, always have Cartan matrix with determinant 1, but I am not 100% sure, nor do I have any reference) See C.C.Xi's lecture notes.  http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~keller/ictp2006/lecturenotes/xi.pdf
The result is: the global dimension of a cellular algebra is finite if and only if the Cartan matrix has determinant 1.

Comment: Thank you very much, Aaron
Is there a finite dimensional algebra $A$ satisfying the following conditions: (1) The Cartan matrix of $A$ is not invertible (2) $A$ has finite globle dimension.

Comment: I can't come up with any example yet, so I would say I don't know.  For most interesting algebras (to me), i.e. the class of directed algebras, hereditary algebras, quasi-hereditary algebras.  They all have finite global dimension with invertible Cartan matrix.  (Also explain why it is hard to come up with one such example...)